# Ruby on Rails application installer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, installation

I want to develop my rails application installer like in joomla in which we can configure database name, username, password, port, host etc. what is the best idea for it. I tried through rake tasks. But don't know is it good idea or not? Please help me.
Is it possible to configure rails application during runtime. If yes, how to configure?
Any ideas, tutorials, links.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano)? It's a great tool to deploy rails applications

I'll suggest you some links about it)

http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/basic-deployment-with-capistrano/

http://railscasts.com/episodes/133-capistrano-tasks

http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html